# ¿Como accedo a los valores de una collection en laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Buenos días chicos necesito acceder a los valores de una colecction para mostrarlos en una vista, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

En el controlador tengo lo siguiente:

```
 public function index(Evento $evento, Request $request)
{
    $tienda = \Session::get('tienda');
    $tienda = collect($tienda);
    dd($tienda);
    return view('tienda.tienda', compact('tienda'));

}

    public function agregar(Evento $evento){

    $tienda = \Session::get('tienda');
    if ($tienda = null) {
        $tienda = $evento;
        \Session::put('tienda', $tienda);
        return view('tienda.inscribir', compact('tienda'));
    }
    else{

        \Session::forget('tienda');
         $tienda = $evento;
        \Session::put('tienda', $tienda);
        return view('tienda.inscribir', compact('tienda'));
    }



}

public function inscribir(Evento $evento, Request $request)
{
    $tienda = \Session::get('tienda');
    $tienda = collect($tienda);
    $inscrito = $request->all();
    $cedula = $request->cedula;
    $tienda[$cedula] = $inscrito;
    Session::put('tienda', $tienda);
    Session::save('tienda', $tienda);

    return view('tienda.inscribir', compact('tienda'));

}
```

Cuando prueba con DD en el método index me muestra la siguiente colección:

[image: Imagen de DD en el metodo index]

Cuando utilizo el metodo inscribir desde la vista(la cual es un formulario) envia los datos y lo guarda, este formulario lo quiero enviar varias veces y se van guardando con la clave:

```
$tienda[$cedula] = $inscrito;
```

Lo que deseo es recorrer esta clave que almacena otras claves y valores y poder acceder a ella desde el método index a placer para mostrar todos los inscritos en esa vista, ademas de los datos del evento! Lo he estado intentando con foreach recorriendo la variable $tienda y solo puedo llegarle a la información del evento pero no a la de los inscritos!

Puedo acceder a los valores del evento en la vista por lo menos asi:

```
{{$tienda['nombre']}}
```

Pero si quiero llegar a los datos de la cedula de los inscritos, no lo logro!  Alguno tiene una idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrupa todos los inscritos en una sola propiedad para que los puedas manejar / recorrer más fácil:

```
public function inscribir(Evento $evento, Request $request)
{
    $tienda = \Session::get('tienda');
    $inscrito = $request->all();
    $cedula = $request->cedula;

    if (! isset($tienda['inscritos']) {
        $tienda['inscritos'] = [];
    }

    // agrupa los inscritos en otro array / propiedad
    $tienda['inscritos'][$cedula] = $inscrito;

    Session::put('tienda', $tienda);
    Session::save('tienda', $tienda);

    return view('tienda.inscribir', compact('tienda'));

}
```

En la vista, simplemente iteras la propiedad o índice inscritos:

```
@if (isset($tienda['inscritos']))

    @foreach ($tienda['inscritos'] as $inscrito)

        {{ $inscrito['edad'] }}

    @endforeach

@endif
```

Comment: Saludos Shaz, gracias por responder, pero cuando intento agregar ese indece me dice lo siguiente: ErrorException in Collection.php line 1043: Undefined index: inscritos.. alguna vez lo intente hacer asi pero sin la cedula, pero no me guarda varios inscritos si no que se sobreescribe ese array y no es lo que necesito.

Comment: Seguramente nos estamos equivocando en alguna parte del proceso, pero te garantizo que es la forma más sencilla de hacerlo y sin duda alguna es posible. Ese error sale en qué parte, en el controlador o en la vista?

Comment: sale cuando realizo la inscripción, es decir, cuando uso el método inscribir, este método lo envió desde un  formulario

Comment: Agrega la verificación que puse en el controlador.

Comment: Fino Shaz solo que cuando lo hacia con la conversión a colección en el método inscribir, me generaba un error porque la colección no permite modificación de sus indeces, me imagino que no de la misma manera que los array. Agradecido Shaz!